# Dependent library ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, primefaces

I have an `EJB` project and i'm using `Primefaces` this is how I include Primefaces 6.1 into my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I can deploy my app to `WebLogic 12c` and my application is start running but when I try to invoke any method it throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/model/UploadedFile
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at weblogic.iiop.IDLUtils.isAbstractInterface(IDLUtils.java:486)
    at weblogic.iiop.Utils.isAbstractInterface(Utils.java:533)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.genWriteParam(StubGenerator.java:376)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.genMarshalingCode(StubGenerator.java:334)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.generateInnerTryCatch(StubGenerator.java:291)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.generateOuterTryCatch(StubGenerator.java:270)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.getCodeForMethod(StubGenerator.java:257)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.addMethod(StubGenerator.java:251)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.addMethods(StubGenerator.java:225)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.<init>(StubGenerator.java:74)
    at weblogic.corba.utils.RemoteInfo.createStubs(RemoteInfo.java:314)
    at weblogic.servlet.ClasspathServlet.getIIOPStubClassSource(ClasspathServlet.java:578)
    at weblogic.servlet.ClasspathServlet.getGeneratedClassSource(ClasspathServlet.java:504)
    at weblogic.servlet.ClasspathServlet.findSourceFromApplicationContainer(ClasspathServlet.java:462)
    at weblogic.servlet.ClasspathServlet.findResource(ClasspathServlet.java:367)
    at weblogic.servlet.ClasspathServlet.doGet(ClasspathServlet.java:224)
    at weblogic.servlet.ClasspathServlet.service(ClasspathServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:357)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:318)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:186)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at weblogic.iiop.IDLUtils.isAbstractInterface(IDLUtils.java:486)
    at weblogic.iiop.Utils.isAbstractInterface(Utils.java:533)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.genWriteParam(StubGenerator.java:376)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.genMarshalingCode(StubGenerator.java:334)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.generateInnerTryCatch(StubGenerator.java:291)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.generateOuterTryCatch(StubGenerator.java:270)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.getCodeForMethod(StubGenerator.java:257)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.addMethod(StubGenerator.java:251)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.addMethods(StubGenerator.java:225)
    at weblogic.corba.rmic.StubGenerator.<init>(StubGenerator.java:74)
    at weblogic.corba.utils.RemoteInfo.createStubs(RemoteInfo.java:314)
    at weblogic.servlet.ClasspathServlet.getIIOPStubClassSource(ClasspathServlet.java:578)
    at weblogic.servlet.ClasspathServlet.getGeneratedClassSource(ClasspathServlet.java:504)
    at weblogic.servlet.ClasspathServlet.findSourceFromApplicationContainer(ClasspathServlet.java:462)
    at weblogic.servlet.ClasspathServlet.findResource(ClasspathServlet.java:367)
    at weblogic.servlet.ClasspathServlet.doGet(ClasspathServlet.java:224)
    at weblogic.servlet.ClasspathServlet.service(ClasspathServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

I tried with other `Primefaces` versions, but the same error occured. I tried to build without `<scope>compile</scope>` didn't change anything. What should I try?

Comment: The fact that a PrimeFaces class cannot be found by your project is not a PrimeFaces problem but a packaging/deployment problem (Maven? Manual?) So check where it is deployed and from where you want to use it. Most likely a packaging problem (PrimeFaces cannot be deploy in an 'EJB' project, just in an EAR or a WAR...

Comment: My packaging in this project now looks like this :  <packaging>jar</packaging>

Comment: Then **that** is your problem... Learn about EAR/WAR/JAR packaging, webapps and how it should all be done from maven. Totally not 'java-ee' (as the api) or a PrimeFaces problem

Comment: Ok thank you i will check that!